# Combine two different graphics into a single one with Easel.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, createjs

how do I make below two instance into single one for animation, Code is given below:

```
 var x = new createjs.Bitmap("img1.png");
 var b = new createjs.Text("A","normal 20px Arial");
 stage.addChild(x,b);
 stage.update();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Containers.

http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html

```
var x = new createjs.Bitmap("img1.png");
var b = new createjs.Text("A","normal 20px Arial");
var myContainer = new createjs.Container();
myContainer.addChild(x,b);
stage.addChild(myContainer);
stage.update();
```